# Search for more than 255 characters long string in VBA WORD

Tags: string, vba, find, ms-word

I have a Word document where I would like to search for a text and if found perform a certain action but I'm getting an `runtime error 5854` stating that my search string is too long. I have been searching and trying different things since yesterday but can't come up with a working code. 
I would be thankful if some of you guys could help me with this.

```
Sub FindTextAndHighlight()
    Dim srchTxt As Variant
    srchTxt = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. "        
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
     .Text = srchTxt
     .Forward = True
     .Execute
        If .Found = True Then
           .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
           .Wrap = wdFindStop
           .Parent.Bold = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What about creating a function which takes a search string argument and the splits at 255 charachters and performs the search? You wouldn't find whole paragraphs but if the exist in that way they would still be found.

Comment: I need to find whole paragraph because the final goal is to add a comment on the whole found text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use the `IntStr` function to find the start and then add the `srchTxt` string length to it to find the range in the document.

I have included some sort of an error handle if the `srchTxt` is not found.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindTextAndHighlight()

    Dim FoundStart As Long
    Dim FoundEnd As Long
    Dim DocContent As String
    Dim srchTxt As String
    Dim srchTxtLength As Long
    Dim FoundRange As Range

    srchTxt = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. "
    srchTxtLength = Len(srchTxt)

    DocContent = ActiveDocument.Content

    ' using -1 to include the first character of the srchTxr found
    FoundStart = InStr(1, DocContent, srchTxt, vbTextCompare) - 1

    If FoundStart > 0 Then
        FoundEnd = FoundStart + srchTxtLength

        Set FoundRange = ActiveDocument.Range(FoundStart, FoundStart + srchTxtLength)

        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            With FoundRange
                   .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                   .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End If
    Else

        MsgBox "Seach String: " & vbCr & vbCr & srchTxt & vbCr & vbCr & "Not Found!"

    End If
End Sub
```

Have the search as a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindTextAndHighlight()

    Dim FoundStart As Long
    Dim FoundEnd As Long
    Dim DocContentSearchRange As Range
    Dim srchTxt As String
    Dim srchTxtLength As Long
    Dim FoundRange As Range

    srchTxtShort = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
    srchTxtLong = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. "
    srchTxtLength = Len(srchTxtLong)

    Set DocContentSearchRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set FoundRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    With DocContentSearchRange.Find
        .Text = srchTxtShort
        .MatchCase = True
    End With

    Do While DocContentSearchRange.Find.Execute

        If DocContentSearchRange.Find.Found Then

            FoundRange.Start = DocContentSearchRange.Start
            FoundRange.End = FoundRange.Start + srchTxtLength
            FoundRange.Select

            If InStr(1, FoundRange.Text, srchTxtLong, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            With FoundRange
                   .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                   .Font.Bold = True
            End With

            Else

                MsgBox "Seach String: " & vbCr & vbCr & srchTxtLong & vbCr & vbCr & "Not Found!"

            End If

            DocContentSearchRange.Start = FoundRange.End

        End If   'If  DocContentSearchRange.Find.Found
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice trick! I will try to adapt it however there is an `runtime error 4608` when I run the code. Seems it's related to the -1

Comment: @Stackgeek on which line do you get the RTE 4608? Is it the `FoundStart = ...` line? I have tested the code with the `srchTxt` inside a larger body of text as well as the word doc only having `srchTxt`. But I do see is that you included a space after the fullstop in the `srchTxt` string. So if you are searching the document and using just the string as the body without the the additional space at the end it will give a runtime error because of the missing space. See my modified answer which includes a bit of error handling in checking that the `srchTxt` was found

Comment: Nice @Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen , in fact the error was related to the line you stated and the new code you provide works just fine when I removed the trailing space. Thank you for the time and the effort.

Comment: I've tried to tweak the code to fit my needs but I figured out that it just doesn't do the work as I wanted it since when using a loop it just searchs in the text for a word starting with similar word in the `srchTxt` and select that text from `FoundStart` to `FoundEnd` as `FoundRange` even when the two texts are different. Do you think it would be workable to compare each word from `FoundStart` to `FoundEnd` so to validate if it's the right matching text and only then set it as `FoundRange`? What do you think about that? It's the only solution I can think of @Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen.

Comment: @Stackgeek try it now. I added `vbTextCompare` to the `InStr` which should then only return exact word for word matches. It will only find the first case of `srchTxt` in the document. For the Loop if will be a bit hard because the you will need to shift the starting points of the `DocContentRange` and then also in the `Range` object characters are a bit different to what you will get from using the `Instr`. What you could try is search for the maximum number of `Charaters` and then do a text compare for the next amount of `Characters`. Look at the new second part to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the feedback's late  @Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen, It's only today I'm testing your last code and I'm so thankfull for the time you devoted to solve this. Thank you, It just solves my problem. Now I can move foward. thank you again.